# PHP File Upload to remote server

Tags: php, file-upload, plesk, remote-server, hosts-file

I am currently having problems with testing a known working file upload script while migrating a site to a new server.

I have migrated the entire site to the new server and everything works as it should apart from the original file upload script. I have not pointed the domain names to the new server as yet, accessing it through changing my hosts file on my local machine.

Before writing a simple upload test script, could there be any reason I am missing that is preventing my file uploads from working - for example, security issues?

Is it likely that the file upload directory location is pointing to the original server?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more detail about the problem; simply saying that it "isn't working" doesn't really allow for any diagnosis. Do you have any error messages? Does it crash or just silently fail? etc. Those points are important, but in the meanwhile, check for config differences between the servers. Specifically, look for php.ini settings that might be different, and also web server config, file permissions, and software versions (eg php version).

Answer (score -1):

Please, put all the files in the content folder directly to the public directory of the live server.
E.g: Select all in the content folder and paste it directly on the public folder.

Comment: I see you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead or guesses